# how to share images on instagram using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');
```

Here we have `Facebook` code implemention for sharing data, but we need similar code for sharing images on `Instagram`.

How do I share  images on `Instagram` using `jQuery`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sorry You can't do this As it's Official Document says No Upload images via API.**

Please check The Instagram API documentation:
https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

See Below Text :

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> - Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>     from within the app.
> - We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the
>     Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to
>     ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our
>     platform.

So As of now you can't do this.

Hope It will help you.